# combine two variables in query in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm having some trouble with what may be a simple question.

I need to be able to query two separate variables as a key using doctrine, but I'm not sure if I need to update the entity schema (I'd rather not, and it seems overkill) to be able to do this.

I'm currently needing to query a number of different items in a single DQL query in one field.  I've been doing something like this:

```
        $qb->select('r')->from('Bundle:Reviews\Review', 'r')
        ->leftJoin('Bundle:Bibliographies\PersonalName', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.biblio = r.id')
        ->leftJoin('r.biblio', 'bib')
        ->where( 'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR p.surname LIKE ?1' );
```

so far so good.  The problem I have is that unlike `author` in the Review entity, which includes both surname and first name, stored automatically like `surname, givenName`, on the PersonalName table (which exists as a one-to-many against Bibliography), there's no single field for both.  I have surname, but what I really need is something like this:

```
   ->where( 'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR "p.surname", "p.givenName" LIKE ?1' );
```

which of course wont work.

To make this simpler, is there a way to do something like create a variable in the Repository that is a composite, define it as a parameter (e.g. `$params[3]` and then do something like this>

```
    ->where( 'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR ?3 LIKE ?1' );
```

Otherwise, I might be fine with doing it in the entity, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

The PersonalName entity has something like this:

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="given_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $givenName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $surname;
```

Is there an easy way of simply creating a new attribute that is a combination of surname and givenName without having to update the entity?  I've been trying to find things in the manual but, alas no dice.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit for clarification:**

All I really need is in my where clause to give me something like this:

```
->where( 'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR (CONCAT(p.surname,CONCAT(", ",p.givenName)) LIKE ?1)' )
```

Unfortunately, where I was getting perfectly good results earlier searching on surname, or a substring of author, I am now getting zero results at all, which makes little sense to me, as there is a clear `OR`.  I'm not sure where this is breaking the query.

Comment: I don't think I understand... why not just do `author = ?1 OR surname = ?1 OR givenName = ?1` ? If you need to query the combination of sur+givenName you can add `OR CONCAT(surname,CONCAT(" ",givenName)) = ?1` to that.

Comment: @ccKep this looks like a good approach (specifically the CONCAT part) however when I do this, it somehow breaks my query and I get zero results.  I have tried this `->where( 'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR (CONCAT(p.surname,CONCAT(", ",p.givenName)) LIKE ?1)' )` (wrapping the OR statement in parens) but the fact it's breaking the query makes no sense to me.  shouldn't it at least pull the results of author?

Comment: @ccKep thanks!  I just realized there's a problem with double quotes inside single quotes in DQL, but you response essentially answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the advice I got above from @ccKep sent me in the right direction.  However, apparently for some reason DQL does not like double quotes inside single quotes.

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
->where( "bib.author LIKE ?1 OR CONCAT(p.surname,CONCAT(', ',p.givenName)) LIKE ?1" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this query:

```
$qb->select('r')->from('Bundle:Reviews\Review', 'r')
        ->leftJoin('Bundle:Bibliographies\PersonalName', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.biblio = r.id')
        ->leftJoin('r.biblio', 'bib')
        ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
             $qb->expr()->like('bib.author', '?1')
             $qb->expr()->like('p.surname', '?2')
        ));

$qb->setParameter(1, $searchTerm);
$qb->setParameter(2, $searchTerm);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really answering my question, and this does pretty much the same thing I'm already doing, but less.   I need both to be querying off the same search term (hence the `?1` twice).  I can get bib.author and p.surname fine;  as I mentioned, that part is working without trouble.   What I need to do is to find a way to combine p.surname and p.givenName as a *key* in the query. Basically one search term (which I already have) but which can match against two attributes combined as one.

Comment: Well, you just bind the same parameter twice. Check my edit.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I'm being clear.   I don't have any trouble getting both bib.author OR p.surname.  What I need to be able to get is bib.author OR a combination of surname and given name, e.g.  "Smith, John" so that when someone searches under say, "Smith" or "Smith, John" or "Smith, J" it brings up accurate results.  The problem has nothing to do with the parameters being fed to the query, the problem is with the key itself.   The review entity has one field where these are stored as surname, givenName.  PersonalName doesnt.   Anyway, I'm attempting to handle this with concatenation

Comment: Standard queries cannot help you. Please read about fullindex search.

Comment: Use `'bib.author LIKE ?1 OR (CONCAT(p.surname,", ",p.givenName) LIKE ?1)'` then. What if someone has three names, and user decide to completely mix search string\?

Comment: You make a good point, however in this particular case, the middle name is included in the givenName string (yes, I know it's odd, but that's following standard MARC citation rules.  But it does make it easier.)